# Register Application class in Manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have one Application class to keep the global state of my application. But I'm unable to register it in Manifest file? Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 400, accepted):

If it derives from Application, add the fully qualified (namespace + class name) as the `android:name` parameter of the application element in your manifest.

```
<application
        android:name="com.you.yourapp.ApplicationEx"
```

Or if the class' package can be described as relative to the `package` in the `manifest` tag, then just start with a `.`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.you.yourapp">

    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationEx"
```

Comment: The documentation says "fully qualified name". I have one time experienced a 3rd party tool interpreting this literally, and not working when trying to find the application class, if specified relatively. 
Just a warning.

Answer (score 13):

but in case you are already using some library like branch.io's library then most probably your manifest

`<application name="">`

property will already have some name like

```
`<application name="io.referral.BranchApp">
```

in that case you need to first extend your application class, like below:

```
public class Application extends BranchApp
```

and then register your application in manifest as:

```
android:name="absdevelopers.com.brankreferal.Application"
```

this works perfectly for me :)
i hope it helps someone in trouble :)

Comment: its been a while you wrote this answer but what if i want to add branch.io and clevertap at the same time. Im getting confused how to deal with name tag in manifest. please help me out.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a MultiDex application you will already have "android:name" in use so instead extend `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication`:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {...}
```

And add it to the Android manifest:

```
android:name="app.package.MyApplication"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the activity is included as a dependency that you can lauch a class this should solve it in 2021.

Add  `tools:ignore="MissingClass"` to your activity element in the Android manfifest file

example

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/LicensesTheme"
            tools:ignore="MissingClass"/>
```