# Android and the mediator design pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns, mediator

I am fairly new to android and after reading a book and taking alot of tutorials i am about to create my first "real" app.

My question is rather simple does: Is the mediator design pattern still a good choice when designing android apps?

If yes is there any design patterns you should avoid when programming android apps?

if no is there any substitude to the mediator pattern you could use to have a collection of your instances of the different objects?

Comment: How do you want to use mediator? You probably want to avoid singleton.

Comment: @MaciejGórski for instance i have a user object that all of my activities needs to know of. And why wouldi want to avoid singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a model class (let's call it `MyModel`) and creating object of this class in `Application.onCreate` (not `Activity.onCreate`).

After that adding getter for that, so you can get this model from any `Activity` or `Service` like this:

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
MyModel model = app.getMyModel();
User user = model.getCurrentUser();
```

etc.

Also creating `BaseActivity` class can save you typing if you create method there `protected MyModel getModel()` which returns model from the first 2 lines of the code above.

**Edit:**

You need to create a class that extends `Application` and register this class in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

This is how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929927/2183804

**Edit (about singleton):**

It is said to be an anti-pattern (not only on Android). In Android I have seen people ending with singleton with accessor like MySingleton.getInstance(Context), because they needed Context anyway, e.g. for SharedPrefs or DB access. This is what Application is for, so there is no need to create additional, hackish entity, which could be used in a wrong way: MySingleton.getInstance(null) from a place where there is no Context available. This could lead to NPE after process is killed and restarted.

Comment: How do i create it on Application.onCreate()? where do i find this. And isnt what you are suggesting a singleton?

Comment: Application is another component. There exists only one instance, but it is not a singleton (doesn't have static accessor). See my edit.

Comment: Thank you or your answer it was very helpfull could you by any chance explain to me why you want to avoid singleton?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen added some info about singletons