# How to stop a currently executing command

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-runtime, java-threads

```
int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        String[] cmd = new String[] { "logcat", "-f",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/log.txt", "-v", "time" };
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            thread.start();

        }
    });

    Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

    Button addLog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addLog);

    addLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.e("logTag", Integer.toString(count));
            count ++ ;

        }
    });
}
```

I want to start saving my app's log using `start` button and stop it using `stop`.
The `addLog` button is used to see if more lines are being added to `log.txt` file.
The `start` button works properly but the problem is it never ends with `stop`.
Even after pressing `stop`, when I press `addLog` button and check the `log.txt`
file, I see last lines have been added.
What is my fault ?

I need to start the stream, close this activity and take a tour in other activities then come back and shut the logging machine down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use @hegazy method and save reference to process in your [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. Don't forget to [register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929562/register-application-class-in-manifest) it in your manifest. Hope you've got my idea.

Something like that:

```
((App)getApplicationContext).process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

and than take this when you need it:

```
((App)getApplicationContext).process.exec("logcat -d");
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Now I have a new problem.
If the user closes my application , the entire app process will be destroyed but the logging machine is still online. And then the reference to the `process` object is lost and I can't stop the stream after reopening my activity.
can you help me ?

Comment: It other question. Close this one and start new one. Don't forget to mark my answer as right one

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can achieve that by saving the Process in a variable that is returned by the Runtime's exec() method and call `destroy()` on that variable.

> public abstract void destroy ()
>
> Terminates this process and closes any associated
>   streams.

Let's record the Process as a global variable;

```
private Process p;
```

and when executing it

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

and this how it's stopped.

```
void stopProcess() {
     if (p != null) {
         p.destroy();
     } else {
         Log.d(TAG, "stopProcess: p==null");
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know it will work but I have another problem which stops me using the method you explained.
I need to start the stream, close this activity and take a tour in other activities then come back and shut the logging machine down.
can you help me ? @hegazy

Comment: would you answer please ?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't available. Do you still have any problems?