# Pass object to another activity (without Parcelable?)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jreddit

I need to pass object `user` to another activity. I know I should use `Parcelable`, but I can't edit `User` class, because it is used from maven repository.

Is it here any other way how can I pass `user` object? Or how to locally edit class from maven repository?

Comment: You can probably use a event bus with sticky event

Comment: I think you should read all users in an arraylist, Create a variable of user type, get/find/match the user object that you want to pass to another activity (best with for loop) with the items in arraylist , once got/found/matched the user - assign the value to the variable that is created above, and then you can call any method and pass the variable as a parameter to another activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Application class for this purposes.
what you need is:

1. create a class which derives from Application.
2. declare the class in the AndroidManifest.xml (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929562/register-application-class-in-manifest))
3. create a object variable of type User in it (also getter and setter).
4. assign the user object in first activit through:

   `MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
    app.setUser(user);`
5. retrieve the object in other activity through:

   `MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
   User user = app.getUser();`

BUT: take care, after you restart you app (go in background and open it again), a new Application object will be created, where the User is null, take care of that then.

This problem can be read [here](http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize the object into some kind of string representation. The easiest way to do this is to convert the object into a JSON string, pass the string to the other activity via intent and convert the string back into the original object.

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing is just converting the object into Json and then sending as a String using Intent. Then you can't catch it and parse Json.

P.S. Using google's Gson class making this very easy. https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/