# Register Application class in Manifest?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-applicationinfo

i wanna register my overrided Application class in the manifest file

already asked questionn (didnt help my case) [Register Application class in Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929562/register-application-class-in-manifest)

in the above question. the user got his answer . but in my case . android:name="" is filled by android name="io.branch.refferal.branchApp"

if i replace that name with my application class name, my branch api does'nt work.

so, how do i register my application class in manifest file

p.s. i have made application file to use chrisjenx's Calligraphy api, to set my font for the entire application

code snippet:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp"
    >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**my application class below :**

```
package absdevelopers.com.brankreferal;

import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;


public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault("fonts/My-font.ttf");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your package name + class name for the Manifest value.

If you want to use the BranchApp features, though, you will need to extend that instead of the raw Application class.

```
package absdevelopers.com.brankreferal;

import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig
import io.branch.referral.BranchApp;

public class Application extends BranchApp
```

Then use your Application in the Manifest

```
<application
    android:name="absdevelopers.com.brankreferal.Application"
```

Comment: @jared burrows - please read both the questions and anwers properly, you'll know the difference in both. that was a sad call from a guy with such a high repo :)

Comment: @cricket_007 - thank you very much , it worked like a charm :)

Comment: @AmanRana You may want to rename your `Application` class to not conflict with `android.app.Application`