# Fragment doesn't get value from ViewModel

Tags: java, android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I have an single activity application with jetpack navigation, I need an object variable for all my application in many fragments. So I use a ViewModel, and I've created a Parent Fragment class which provide the ViewModel :

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var myData : CustomClass? = null
    ...
}

open class ParentFragment : Fragment {
    val model : MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
    lateinit var myData : CustomClass

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        model.myData?.let {
            myData = it
        }
    }
}
```

`myData`should not be null where I use `ParentFragment`, but sometimes, randomly I get   `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property myData has not been initialized` when I use `myData`

Is it possible that my ViewModel doesn't keep `myData`? How can I be sure that my property has been initialized ?

**UPDATE : Try 1**

I've tried this code in my `ParentFragment`:

```kotlin
open class ParentFragment : Fragment {
    val model : MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
    lateinit var backingData : CustomClass
    val myData : CustomClass
        get() {
            if (!::backingData.isInitialized)
                model.getData()?.let {
                    backingData = it
                }
            return backingData
        }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        model.getData?.let {
            backingData = it
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem doesn't disappear when I call `myData`, it seem's the `ViewModel`loses my data

**UPDATE 2 : More code details**

Before to go inside a `fragment` which extends `ParentFragment`, I set my data in `ViewModel` and then I navigate to the next `fragment` as below :

```kotlin
// Inside FirstFragment
if (myData != null) {
    model.setData(myData)
    findNavController().navigate(FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstToNextFragment())
}
```

Is it possible that my `NavController` does navigation before the data was setted ?

**EDIT 3 : Try to use custom Application class**

According to an answer below, I've implemented a `custom Application class`, and I've tried to pass my object through this class :

```kotlin
class MyApplication: Application() {

    companion object {
        var myObject: CustomClass? = null
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, there is no change for me. Maybe my object is too big to allocate correctly ?

Comment: How do you initialise `myObject` in the view model?

Comment: @tynn I initialise it in a `fragment`, then I pass it to the `ViewModel` and then I use it in each `fragments` that extend `ParentFragment`

Comment: It sounds like a race condition. Could you provide the code for this fragment?

Comment: Of course, you can check my last edit, but it's a simple code

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
  var myObject : CustomClass? = null
  ...
}

open class ParentFragment : Fragment {
  lateinit var model : MyViewModel by activityViewModels()


  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    if(model.myObject == null) {
        // initialize myObject, will be persisted by ViewModel
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `MyViewModel` and its member objects **should not** hold any references to `Activity`, `Fragment`, or `Context`, that include any indirect references to `Context` such as UI Views.

I will not recommend `LiveData` (or `MutableLiveData`) in your case, because a "feature" of `LiveData` is that their values are posted and updated asynchronously, hence call to `observe` may be too late.

Comment: Thank for your answer. The problem is that I can't initialize `myObject` anywhere, I initialize it in a certain fragment with a lot of params in this fragment, but others fragments don't have access to theses params

Comment: Regardless of how or where `myObject` is initialized, the purpose of `ViewModel` is to enable sharing data between different fragments. Once initialized, the data in `ViewModel` should not be "lost".

Comment: Yes but it seems that my `ViewModel` loses my data, or maybe my data isn't set when I go to my `Fragment`, but before to navigate I set the data correctly. So, there is something that I don't understand

Comment: What is `myData`? And why are you checking if it is not null `if (myData != null)` in order to initialize your viewModel object?

Comment: `myData` is my custom object that I need to keep but which disappear I don't know why. When I do the check `if (myData != null)` inside my fragment, is it to test if I can put the object in the `ViewModel`

Comment: Can you show the part of code where you initialize `myData`?

Answer (score 3):

Your wording hints some design flaws, namely:
You are refering to your data as object variable and to make it accessible at all times you chose to use a ViewModel. To me it sounds that you overthought your options.

**Suggestion**

Your object lifecycle appears to be managed manually by yourself. Therefore you should just use a static variable. This translates to Kotlin as a property within an (companion) object. I suggest you declare a custom Application class within your manifest and in its `onCreate`-method, you allocate your object and put it into the companion object of this class. Of course you can allocate it at any given time later on as well.
This will result in the following:

- Access is always be possible via `YourApplication.mData` within your code.
- Objects which relying on implementations outside the JVM can be managed properly. 
  For example: If you already bound to a port you won't be able to do this on a successive call - When the viewModel restores its state, for example. Maybe the underlying implementation did not report an error back to Java but allocating did not succeed. To manifest this assumption you would need to provide an description of your object variable. But As an famous example in the world of Android for this behaviour, try creating a soundPool via the SystemServices. You will experience lints about the correct usage of this object.
- Deallocating can be done in the `onTerminate()` method of your 
  Application.class **// edit_4:** Doc of super.onTerminate() says the system will just kill your app. Therefore one needs to deallocate within an your activity. See code snippets below.

**Clarification**

The ViewModel of the JetPack Components is mainly responsible for saving and restoring the state of the view and binding to its model. 
Meaning it handles the lifecycle across activities, fragments and possibly views. This is why you have to use an activity as the lifecycle owner in case you want to share an viewModel across multiple fragments. But I still suppose your object is more complex than just a POJO and my above suggestion results in your expected behaviour. 
Also note that when multithreading, you shall not rely on the correct order of the lifecycle methods. There are only limited lifecycle-callbacks which are guaranteed to be called in a specific order by the android system, but the frequently used ones are unfortunately not included here. In this case, you should start processing at a more approrpiate time.

> Even though the data should be similiar to the previous state, the exact reference depends on the hashCode implementation, but this is an JVM specific.

// edit:

ParentFragment is also bad naming, since you created a class which others  shall inherit instead of refer to. If you want to access a specific variable within all your fragments, this needs to be implemented as an object (Singleton), since the Navigation component will prevent you from accessing the fragmentManager directly.
In plain android, one fragment can always refer to its parentFragment, **iff** this parentFragment has used its own childFragmentManager to commit the fragmentTransaction. Meaning also that fragments added by your Activity-fragmentManager have never an parentFragment.

// edit_2+3:

```
ViewModelProvider(activity!!, ViewModelFactory())[clazz]
```

is the correct call for creating and accessing a sharedViewModel:
The lifecycle owner needs to be the activity, otherwise after each fragmentTransaction done there will be a callback to the onCleared() method and the viewModel will release all references to avoid memory leaks.

// edit_4:
That your object was not correctly initialized was just an assumption which only would oocure if you tried to initialize it again. For example if you use an get()-method on an val where not appropriate. 
Nonetheless, handling your object this way ensures that its lifecycle is outside your fragments. Here is an code example to clarify my wording:

// edit_5: To assert that the object reference is not damaged, include null checking (only if construction of CustomClass is non trivial)

[Declare your CustomApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929927/6783797)

```
class CustomApplication : Application() {

    companion object SharedInstances {

        /**
         *   Reference to an object accessed in various places in your application.
         *
         *   This property is initialized at a later point in time. In your case, once
         *   the user completed a required workflow in some fragment.
         *
         *   @Transient shall indicate that the state could also be not Serializable/Parcelable
         *              This _could_ require manually releasing the object.
         *              Also prohibits passing via safeArgs
         */
        @Transient var complex: CustomClass? = null
    }

}
```

Intialization and Usage within your classes:

```
class InitializeComplexStateFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        if (complex != null) return@onViewCreated // prohibit successive initialization.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) { /* The fragment was recreated but the object appears to be lost. */ }
        // do your heavy lifting and initialize your data at any point.
        CustomApplication.SharedInstances.complex = object : CustomClass() {
            val data = "forExampleAnSessionToken"
            /* other objects could need manual release / deallocation, like closing a fileDescriptor */
            val cObject = File("someFileDescriptorToBindTo")
        }
    }

}

class SomeOtherFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        CustomApplication.SharedInstances.complex?.let {
                // do processing
            }
            ?: propagateErrorStateInFragment()
    }

    private fun propagateErrorStateInFragment() { throw NotImplementedError("stub") }
}
```

Deallocation if required

```
class SomeActivity: Activity() {

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        /* with multiple activities the effort increases */
        CustomApplication.complex?.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Effectively, my `object` is very complex. I've tried to pass the object as you said in a custom `Application class`, but I still have the problem. If I understood correctly what you say, it's possible that my allocation to `MyApplication` may not have been done ?

Comment: Yes, this could be possible, but it depends on your object and you would probably be aware of if this would be the case. Anyway, I added an example listing for handling an object within your entire application. What does your object consist of (Strings, Ints or references to which object)?

Comment: Thank your for your exemple. My object is a photobook with a lot of ref (strings, photos, ref to many objects...). Why the keyword `transient` is needed in `CustomApplication` ?

Comment: Regarding your question in your third edit: Exceeding the memory results in a clear exception. The 'transient' keyword: you should just be aware that there are objects which can not be used for serialization. A companion object is a java static class, therefore it survives orientation changes. My impl forced you to use the correct reference, even on another thread. Therefore I conclude that you are requesting the reference before the constructor call is finished, which can only be the case if your requesting thread differs.

Answer (score 1):

You can check by using `isInitialized` on your property.
As the documentation says:

> Returns true if this lateinit property has been assigned a value, and false otherwise.

You could initialize your property as null and do a null-check with the `let` as you already do though, no need to use `lateinit` and be careful with it, it is not a substitute for using a nullable var

Comment: I'll try to use ```null```and ```null-check```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
   var mData: MutableLiveData<CustomClass>? = null
   init {
     mData = MutableLiveData<CustomClass>()
     mData!!.value =  CustomClass()
   }
   fun getData(): LiveData<CustomClass>? {
     return mData
   }
}
```

And your fragment :

```
open class ParentFragment : Fragment {
    lateinit var model  : MyViewModel
    lateinit var myObject : CustomClass

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        model =  ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        model.getData()?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            myObject = it
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I used a similar method before (with ```MutableLiveData```), but I had the same error too, it seems that the ViewModel doesn't keep ```mData```value, or the ```observer``` is called too late

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should tie the sharedVM lifecycle to activity and then use the same sharedVM instance in all fragments. Also initialise the myObject in parentFragment/ activity class using setter(). Then get the object using getter().
sample code:

```
// SharedViewModel
var myObject : CustomClass? = null

fun setMyObject(obj : CustomClass?){
   myObject = obj
}

fun getMyObject():CustomClass?{
   return myObject
}

// Activity 
val model: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
model.setMyObject(objectValue)

// ParentFragment
private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
val obj = model.getMyObject()
```

Hope this helps you.Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi, I've tried your answer, but the problem is still here, I have a `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Ady could you please update your piece of code to know how you are trying.