# Delete items from listView Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have this problem when i open the view of "Eventos", im trying to delete from de database the selected items from the listview.

[image]

public class ShowData extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
Button btnDelete;
Module module;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_data);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Eventos");
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewShow);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBorrarElemento);
    module=((Module)getApplication());
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); .....


... listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            module.setGvalue_titulo(arrayList.get(position));
            module.setGvalue_descripcion(arrayList.get(position));
            module.setGvalue_fecha(arrayList.get(position));
            module.setGvalue_url(arrayList.get(position));
        }
    });


    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            final String str = module.getGvalue_titulo().substring(0, 6);
            if(str == ""){
                Toast.makeText(ShowData.this, "No se ha seleccionado ningun elemento para eliminar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                databaseReference.child("Eventos").child(str).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        databaseReference.child(str).removeValue();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(ShowData.this, "Evento Eliminado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowData.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }); ....
```

The module has the getters and setters necessaries:
[image]

In my manifest, I have this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: At which line of code does that error occur?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to cast your `Application` to `Module`, but it's not `Module`. Well, have you registered your `Module` as custom application implementation in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? If the answer is "no" than this is the exact reason! Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929927/3528524) to check how to do it easily.

Comment: i dont know how, i put one photo to show that i have