# Azure Notification Hubs for Android: How do I handle Data-Messages with a Background-Service?

Tags: java, android, firebase, azure, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to make an app that is able to handle (data-)messages sent by the Azure Notification Hubs. At the current state it sends a Notification when recieving a payload by Azure. While the app is running in the foreground (or still open in the Quick Panel) it has no problems at all and `onPushNotificationReceived()` handles the incoming message just fine, but when removing the app from the Quick Panel I get an error for trying to invoke a null object refrence:

---

```
Logcat
```

```
2021-07-22 15:27:33.675 23017-23053/com.example.fcmtutorial1app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
    Process: com.example.fcmtutorial1app, PID: 23017
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.notificationhubs.NotificationListener.onPushNotificationReceived(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage)' on a null object reference
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.notificationhubs.FirebaseReceiver.onMessageReceived(FirebaseReceiver.java:52)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:13)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.passMessageIntentToSdk(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:8)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleMessageIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:3)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:3)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$EnhancedIntentService(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:1)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

This only happens when sending data messages, since the Firebase Service handles Messages with notification payload without invoking `onPushNotificationReceived()`.

---

I've tried the following to fix this:

- Extending CustomNotificationListener.class with android.app.Service
- Replacing onPushNotificationReceived() with Thunderbirds onMessageReceived()

The first solution resulted in the same error and the second one resulted in no messages at all.

If someone has a way to fix this or knows what could be the fault, I'd be really be happy if you could write an answer :)

Here is the code for both classes (android.app.Service is still included although it didn't work for me). Thanks in advance!

---

```java
MainActivity.class
```

```java
package com.example.fcmtutorial1app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.notificationhubs.NotificationHub;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "Channel1";
    public static final String CHANNEL_2_ID = "Channel2";

    public static String editTextTitle;
    public static String editTextMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createNotificationsChannels();

        NotificationHub.setListener(new CustomNotificationListener());
        NotificationHub.start(this.getApplication(), "spfcmtutorial1nhub", "Endpoint=sb://azurecloudmessaging.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=abc[...]xyz");
    }

    public static void sendCloudMessage(Context context)
    {
        editTextTitle = CustomNotificationListener.title;
        editTextMessage = CustomNotificationListener.body;

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(editTextTitle)
                .setContentText(editTextMessage)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());

        Log.v("MSG", "SENDCLOUDMESSAGE WAS ACTIVATED");
    }

    public void createNotificationsChannels() //Channel 2 is for tests only
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_1_ID,
                    "Channel 1",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            channel1.setDescription("This is Channel 1");

            NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_2_ID,
                    "Channel 2",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            );
            channel2.setDescription("This is Channel 2");

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```java
CustomNotificationListener.class
```

```java
package com.example.fcmtutorial1app;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.notificationhubs.NotificationListener;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomNotificationListener extends Service implements NotificationListener
{
    private static final String TAG = "Message";

    public static String title;
    public static String body;
    public static String dataTitle;
    public static String dataBody;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service started");
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPushNotificationReceived(Context context, RemoteMessage message) //FATAL EXEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle HERE
    {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = message.getNotification();

        try { title = notification.getTitle(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        try { body = notification.getBody(); } catch (Exception e) {}

        Map<String, String> data = message.getData();

        //region LOGGING
        if (message != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Title: " + title);
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + body);
        }
        else { Log.e(TAG, "ERROR, no message found"); }

        if (data != null)
        {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet())
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "key, " + entry.getKey() + "value " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        else { Log.e(TAG, "ERROR, no data found"); }
        //endregion

        Log.v("VERBOSE",  data.get("property1"));

        MainActivity.sendCloudMessage(context);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```java
AndroidManifest.xml
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fcmtutorial1app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FCMTutorial1App">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".CustomNotificationListener"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question, we'll need to discuss some Android lifecycle concepts as documented at https://developer.android.com:

- [Process and Application Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle)
- [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

In the code you provide above, you call `NotificationHub.setListener` in your application's primary entrypoint, `MainActivity`. As you see, this works when your end user has started the application manually because `MainActivity.onCreate` gets invoked.

However, there's a second entrypoint in your scenario: `FirebaseMessagingService` starting the application when a data-only notification is received in the background. This is subtle and easy to miss - because if the payload contains a `notification` component, Android will still route to `MainActivity` when the notification is clicked in the system tray.

In this case `MainActivity` isn't involved, so `MainActivity.onCreate` and `NotificationHub.setListener` are never called as the application initialized, and the [following line from the stack trace](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-android/blob/ef9ac0d33761d596bc63b59492a8ac1ffa64cd34/notification-hubs-sdk/src/fcm/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/messaging/notificationhubs/FirebaseReceiver.java#L52) encounters a null reference:

```
mHub.getInstanceListener().onPushNotificationReceived(this.getApplicationContext(), remoteMessage);
```

To fix this, you'll need to call `NotificationHub.setListener` somewhere that gets called anytime the application gets initialized, regardless of the entrypoint.

The most natural choice is to setup the NotificationHub at the Application level by extending `android.app.Application`, overriding the [`onCreate()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#onCreate()), and [updating your manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929562/register-application-class-in-manifest).

Comment: Thanks! Creating a new class and extending it worked really well ^^

Comment: I'm glad! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @MarStr I configged as you said, and it works now. But it lead to another problem.

`+ I use azure notification hub for android sdk v1.1.6
+ I use firebase Data message
+ I set azure listener on Application onCreate()`

But when I turn off my phone sceen for about 15-20 minutes, I send a data message, and no push come to my phone.
I think when use data message, Azure hub need to keep a service to listen firebase push, but this service's killed when phone off screen too long.
Am I right, @MarStr?

Please help me to check this. Thanks very much.