# Starting a service without having a launcher activity in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, notifications

I have service where i need to trigger a simple notification without needing a launcher activity so basically an app without activity , but for some reason it is not working cause i also tried to run service from terminal it did not work , is there any to make this work , Thank you

- This is my Service

```
public class NetworkService extends android.app.Service {
  
  private NotificationManager notificationManager;
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      showNetworkChangeNotification();

  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
  }
  
  private void showNetworkChangeNotification() {
      notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("network_change_channel", "Network Change Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
          notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
      }

      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.custom_ui_layout);
      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,"This is a testing text");

      
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

      NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "network_change_channel")
              .setContentTitle("Network ")
              .setContentText("Sample")
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_circle_notifications_24)
              .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
              .setContent(remoteViews)
              .addAction(R.drawable.baseline_circle_notifications_24, "Reset", getCancelPendingIntent())
              .setAutoCancel(true);

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          startForeground(1, notificationBuilder.build());
      } else {
          notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
      }



  }

  private PendingIntent getCancelPendingIntent() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, NetworkChangeReceiver.class);
      intent.setAction("com.z.widgets.networkChangeReceiver.actionCancelNotification");
      return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
  }
  

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      notificationManager.cancel(1);
      stopSelf();
  }
}
```

- This is my receiver

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
   private NotificationManager notificationManager;
   @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, NetworkService.class);
       if (intent != null && "com.z.widgets.networkChangeReceiver.actionCancelNotification".equals(intent.getAction())) {
           Toast.makeText(context,"Reset Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }

}
```

- This is my Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

   <application
       android:name=".BaseApplication"
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
       android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.WidgetJava"
       tools:targetApi="31">
       

       <service android:name=".NetworkService"
           android:exported="true"
           android:enabled="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               <action android:name="com.example.action.START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
           </intent-filter>
       </service>

       <receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
           android:exported="true"
           android:enabled="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.z.widgets.networkChangeReceiver.actionCancelNotification"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </receiver>


   </application>

</manifest>
```

- This is a screenshot from terminal ( it says service started but
  nothing happens cause notification is supposed to fire up )

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [registering an application class in your manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929562/register-application-class-in-manifest)? Maybe that helps

Comment: Like starting service inside applicatio class ? if so yeah i did but no effect

Comment: Installed apps are installed into a force stopped state.  They need to be manually run to be launched for a first time.  That requires an Activity.  The Activity doesn't need to do anything, but it needs to be run once.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

First, while you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />`, that is a runtime permission. On Android 13 and higher, you need to [request it at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting). That, in turn, will require an activity.

Second, you have:

```
       <service android:name=".NetworkService"
           android:exported="true"
           android:enabled="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               <action android:name="com.example.action.START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
           </intent-filter>
       </service>
```

It appears that you copied part of that `<intent-filter>` from an `<activity>` element. `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` in conjunction with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` is used with activities, specifically those that should appear in the launcher. If you are expecting those lines to cause your service to run, you will be disappointed.

Third, your service has:

```java
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

That points to an activity that you do not have.

Fourth, you have:

```xml
       <receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
           android:exported="true"
           android:enabled="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.z.widgets.networkChangeReceiver.actionCancelNotification"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
```

Broadcasts using an implicit `Intent`, such as just an action string, have largely been banned for several years. It is unclear what code will use an explicit `Intent` that would trigger your receiver.

> i need to trigger a simple notification without needing a launcher activity so basically an app without activity

Unless you are:

- Building your own hardware, or
- Building your own Android firmware to install on some hardware, or
- Are serving as a plugin for some other app, using some SDK that they supply

...then your code will never run. And in those first two cases, you would need code or configuration elsewhere to arrange for your code to run.