Jetpack Compose Hilt Inject ViewModel creation error with Jetpack Compose
I am working with Android 14 api, Kotlin 2.0.0 and I'm using Hilt for dependency injection.
What is wrong with my Hilt config that is preventing the creation of the FirstViewModel?
I get the following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class 
    ui.viewmodels.FirstViewModel
    ...
  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
    ui.viewmodels.FirstViewModel.<init> []
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:3063)
    at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.JvmViewModelProviders.createViewModel(JvmViewModelProviders.kt:38)

I have added an App class
@HiltAndroidApp
class App: Application()

I have added the App class to the AndroidManifest.xml
<application
    android:name=".App"

My main activity has the @AndroidEntryPoint annotation:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {}

My Hilt module:
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DataModules {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesFirstApi(): FirstApi =
        Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:3000").addConverterFactory(
            GsonConverterFactory.create()
        ).build().create(FirstApi::class.java)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFirstRepository(firstApi: FirstApi): FirstRepository{
        return FirstRepositoryImpl(firstApi)
    }
}

The view model in question:
@HiltViewModel
class FirstViewModel @Inject constructor(private val firstRepository: FirstRepository): ViewModel() {
   suspend fun getDetails() = firstRepository.getServices()
}

interface FirstRepository{
    suspend fun getServices(): List<MyObject>
}

class FirstRepositoryImpl(private val firstApi: FirstApi): FirstRepository {
    override suspend fun getServices() = listOf(MyObject())
}

import retrofit2.http.GET

interface FirstApi{
    @GET("services")
    suspend fun getServices(): List<MyObject>
}

The composable in which I am trying to inject:
@Composable
fun Details(
    FirstViewModel: FirstViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    // ...
}

The relevant parts of my module level gradle file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.dagger.hilt.android)
}

dependencies {
    ksp(libs.dagger.compiler)
    ksp(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)
    implementation(libs.hilt.navigation.compose)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.hilt.android.testing)
    testImplementation(libs.hilt.android.testing)
    implementation(libs.hilt.compiler)
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
}

The relevant parts of the version catalog:
[versions]
daggerCompiler = "2.48"
hiltCompilerVersion = "1.2.0"
androidxHiltNavigationCompose = "1.2.0"
hiltAndroidTesting = "2.51.1"
hiltCompiler = "2.51.1"
hiltAndroidVersion = "2.44"
daggerHiltAndroid = "2.44"

[libraries]
dagger-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler", version.ref = "daggerCompiler" }
androidx-hilt-compiler = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltCompilerVersion" }
hilt-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "androidxHiltNavigationCompose" }
hilt-android-testing = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing", version.ref = "hiltAndroidTesting" }
hilt-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltCompiler" }
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hiltAndroidVersion" }

[plugins]
dagger-hilt-android = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "daggerHiltAndroid" }


Please include the entire stack trace of the error

Use hiltViewModel instead of viewModel() in your Composable

using hiltViewModel crashes with the same error. The adnroid docs state use viewModel()
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/libraries#hilt

Scroll down to the next section, there it says: "When using Navigation Compose, always use the hiltViewModel composable function [...]"

Please also provide the relevant entries from the version catalog so we can see which artifacts you actually use.

@ianhanniballake https://elmah.io/tools/stack-trace-formatter/0e998b6d39bf4d1e8bece80e22ad3671/

@Leviathan I have updated the post with detail of the dagger hilt dependencies in use. Using hiltViewModel returns the same error and removing the dependency: androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0 still returns same error

Make sure you have Application class that is annotated with @HiltAndroidApp.

@AdnanHabib Is that is only if you require the app context? nonetheless I have added it and still returns the same error

"I have updated the post with detail of the dagger hilt dependencies in use." -- I don't see that update; are you sure you submitted it?

@succeed According to documentation @HiltAndroidApp is must when using hilt. https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#application-class

@succeed Don't forget to register Application class in manifest. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929927/11512499

@AdnanHabib yeah I have added an App class that extends Application and addes the @HiltAndroidApp annotation.
Updated post with details
returns same error

@succeed: Can you please provide the relevant parts of your version catalog?

@succeed How does libs.hilt.navigation.compose is different from implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)?

switch from ksp to kapt and remove ksp(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler) // "1.2.0".

That's grasping at straws. Why revert to kapt? Instead of guessing we should wait until we have the full picture (i.e. succeed updates the question with the version catalog, as I already asked for three times). Then we can make an informed attempt to answer. All guess work up until then should be minimized.

@Leviathan I have added the complete build gradle and lib versions here https://pl.kotl.in/AnVao86l1 and have also added hilt lib versions to the post.
It appears to be a dependency issue. I have copy the dependencies and gradle build configs from one of the an android sample project that uses kotlin 2.0 and it works. However I need to go through a process of elimination to work out which dependencies were incorrect

Thanks for the update, but we need all relevant information in the question itself. The following is missing: 1. the relevant versions from the [versions] block; 2. the plugin dagger-hilt-android from the [plugins] block; 3. The artifact com.google.dagger:hilt-android, otherwise gradle won't sync; 4. The usage of the dependency hilt-compiler. Please update your question so it contains all relevant information we need to reproduce the problem.

Since you dind't react I took the liberty to assemble what seems to be what you have on a best-effort basis and updated the question. Please verify that it is correct.

@Leviathan fantastic. It works! cheers

You are mixing three different Hilt versions:

2.44: hiltAndroidVersion, daggerHiltAndroid
2.48: daggerCompiler
2.51.1: hiltAndroidTesting, hiltCompiler

The idea of specifying the versions separately is that you can reuse the same version variable for multiple artifacts. Since you always want the same version for all of the above artifacts, remove all version entries except one (rename it to hilt, for example) and set its version to 2.51.1:
hilt = "2.51.1"

Now update the artifacts to only use this version instead.
Note: androidxHiltNavigationCompose has an independent versioning and must stay separate (with version 1.2.0).
With this out of the way you also need to update your module level gradle file.
Throw these two out:
ksp(libs.dagger.compiler)
ksp(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)

And libs.hilt.compiler needs to be provided to ksp instead of implementation:
ksp(libs.hilt.compiler)

That's it, with this cleaned up gradle setup your code should work.

been trying a few hours to fix this and it works! All the different hilt and dagger versions are confusing.
